# How to pass a table or rows to a function in Postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql

Here is the code, the current type of argument is array, but I want to pass a table or rows instead.

```
create or replace function skyband_sortedlist(rest point[]) 
    returns setof point
as $$ 
declare

    last_x integer :=0;
    last_y integer :=0;
begin
    for ipoint in (select s0.x,s0.y from unnest(rest))
    loop 
        if ipoint.x>last_x and ipoint.y<>last_y then
            last_x = ipoint.x;
            last_y = ipoint.y;
            return next;
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A row is represented by a composite type, like

```
CREATE TYPE mytype  AS (
   id integer,
   name text,
   fromdate timestamp with time zone
);
```

You can use such a type as function argument.

For each PostgreSQL table, there automatically exists a type with the same name and columns:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   name text,
   fromdate timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);
```

So you can create a function that takes an array of this type as argument:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(arg mytable[]) RETURNS void
   LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
$$DECLARE
   t mytable;
BEGIN
   FOREACH t IN ARRAY arg LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'id = %', t.id;
   END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

You can call it like this (assuming that there are two rows in `mytable`):

```
SELECT myfunc(array_agg(mytable)) FROM mytable;
NOTICE:  id = 1
NOTICE:  id = 2
┌────────┐
│ myfunc │
├────────┤
│        │
└────────┘
(1 row)
```

Alternatively, you can create a function that takes a cursor as argument:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(arg refcursor) RETURNS void
   LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
$$DECLARE
   t mytable;
BEGIN
   LOOP
      FETCH NEXT FROM arg INTO t;
      EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
      RAISE NOTICE 'id = %', t.id;
   END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

This can be called in a transaction as follows:

```
BEGIN;
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM mytable;
SELECT myfunc('c');

NOTICE:  id = 1
NOTICE:  id = 2
┌────────┐
│ myfunc │
├────────┤
│        │
└────────┘
(1 row)

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks, by the way, will the name of columns be saved after being converted into array? If not, how to access specific column?

Comment: The array is an array of `mytable`, so each of the entries has the attributes of `mytable`. You could reference them like this: `(arg[2]).name`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `ARRAY_AGG` constructor to convert a rowset to an array.  For example, the following expression results in an array of all rows from table t1:

```
(SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t1) FROM t1)
```

Full example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id INT, name TEXT);
INSERT INTO t1 values (1, 'Joe'), (2, 'Arnold');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f1(arg t1[])
 RETURNS SETOF t1
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
SELECT * FROM UNNEST(arg);
$$;

SELECT f1((SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t1) FROM t1));
```