# PostgreSQL, SQL: how to use rows values as parameters in a ready-made function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to use rows in a table as parameters in a function?
For example, I have a simple function that calculates total sales by amount and quantity.

```
SELECT sales from public.my_function(v_amount, v_qty)
```

I have a table with two columns: sum and quantity

```
Amount  QTY
100     5
200     10
300     20
400     30
500     40
```

I want to add another column where there will be a function result for parameters that are in each row.
I try to place columns within a function but it returns me an error.
It seems to me that my try is really wrong:

```
SELECT Amount,
       QTY
       (select sales from public.my_function(select Amount from public.table, select QTY from public.table) as Sales
FROM public.table
```

Result need as :

```
Amount  QTY   Sales
100     5     500
200     10    2000
300     20    6000
400     30    12000
500     40    20000
```

Is there a way to do it right?
Thanks

Comment: [Edit] the question and show the function.

Comment: Hi, sticky bit    My question: Is it possible to use row values as parameters of a ready function. The stage of writing a function itself is something else.

Comment: In Postgres every table is also a type which means a record from that table, so yes, it's possible. But that information won't solve you the syntax errors in your query. But to fix that we need to know what you actually have and want by a [example]. Otherwise the question isn't answerable and should be closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a table or rows to a function in Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43979341/how-to-pass-a-table-or-rows-to-a-function-in-postgresql)

Comment: No Serg, unfortunately, your example describes a function writing step, I ask about parameters in a ready function.

Comment: `select amount, qty, my_function(amount, qty) from table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a `lateral join` if the function returns a table:

```
SELECT Amount, QTY, x.Sales
FROM public.table t cross join lateral
     public.my_function(t.amount, t.qty) x;
```

If it just returns a scalar, then you don't have to do anything special:

```
SELECT t.Amount, t.QTY,
       public.my_function(t.amount, t.qty) as Sales
FROM public.table t;
```