# How to pass a record/row to a function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to understand how to pass a row/record as argument of a function in postgresql and
I found this already existing question [How to pass a table or rows to a function in Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43979341/how-to-pass-a-table-or-rows-to-a-function-in-postgresql) where the selected answer explains really well how to pass a table as argument by  using the array_agg() function.

In that case the argument of the function is an array of the type of the table and  each element of the array matches a row and and each  field of an element of the array, which can be read using the . notation, matches the columns of a row.

What's not explained in the answer is how to pass only one record/row as argument and my thought on that would be to pass a variable of tablename%ROWTYPE type and then use the . notation to access each field of the record like this: variable.field1, variable.field2 and so on.

Is this correct? If it is not, how can I pass a record which has the type of a table row as an argument to a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function should accept a parameter of the same type as your table. Here is an example that returns a boolean, which you can use to filter the table (similar to a `where` clause, but this is just an example)

```
CREATE FUNCTION isvisible(p_row myTable)  RETURNS BOOLEAN
AS $BODY$
  select p_row.myCol = 'whatever';
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

select * from myTable  t where t.isvisible;
select * from myTable  t where isvisible(t);
select * from myTable  t where isvisible(t.*);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a couple of questions: would there be any difference between using myTable or mytable%ROWTYPE as type? What does select p_row.myCol = 'my condition' mean? I only know plpgsql and that line of code doesn't sound familiar.

Comment: it's just an example... do whatever you want using `p_row` inside the function.

Comment: so the line of code select p_row.myCol = 'whatever' just means that you are giving p_row.myCol a different value than the one you used when you initially passed the record as argument?

Comment: no, there is a `select` before. If this particular field has the value "whatever", the `select` - and therefore the whole function - will return TRUE, else FALSE.

Comment: I get it now, I didn't know that the select statement could be used outside of a query and for that purpose.

Comment: ... it is a query, inside the function

Comment: I didn't know that you could use a query with a select statement without from too, but I understand the logic behind that: It's like writing: if  p_row.myCol = 'whatever' then return true else return false end if; in plpgsql